# return value of copy_from_user()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Here is the description of the return value.

```
unsigned long copy_from_user
    (void *to, const void __user *from, unsigned long count)
```

The return value is the amount of memory still to be copied.

What does it really mean? If the return value is 5, are `(count-5)` bytes copied? What is the reason that `(count-5)` bytes are copied only? Is it because size of `to` is smaller than `from` (the system should be crashed then, right)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `copy_from_user` function can fail for various reasons (typically because of an invalid address), copying only part of the requested data, or even none of it.

There's a convention (not quite universally followed) of functions returning 0 to denote success. In the case of `copy_from_user`, defining the result as the number of bytes *not* copied allows it to follow this convention with a fairly simple rule.

Intuitively, it might make more sense for it to return the number of bytes actually *copied*, but the way it's defined allows code that uses it to test for errors in a similar manner as for other functions that return 0 on success. (And in many cases, it doesn't matter *how many* bytes it failed to copy; any non-zero result is just an error.)

If it returns a non-zero value that's less than `count`, indicating a partial copy, it *probably* means that the user-space memory buffer starts within the user process's address space but extends beyond the end of it.